# How to get Windows 10 to recognize my Bose Quietcomfort 35 headphones as headphones instead of an "unspecified device"?

Tags: windows-10, bluetooth, headphones

When I pair my Bose Quietcomfort 35 headphones to my Windows 10 PC via bluetooth, they show up as an unspecified device in the devices and printers area of the control panel instead of an audio output device. How do I get Windows to recognize it?

Comment: how are you pairing the device? Also which driver version are you using?

Comment: @KalamalkaKid I pair it by plugging it in through a USB cable. I don't know how to check which driver version I'm using.

Comment: Pairing like this might be the issue. Have you tried to pair the device as described in the manual (wirelessly)? About the driver. Can you right click on the unspecified device in control panel  then click on Properties and the fgo to the Driver tab and let us know what it says there?

Comment: @KalamalkaKid I tried connecting them wirelessly, but that didn't help. The drivers are version 10.0.18362.1, and I've tried updating them, but Windows says they're up to date.

Comment: ok, can you be more specific about 'that didnt help'? I mean, what was the result of connecting the headphones this way. Its best to describe what you have done in your questions to get more focused answers.

Comment: @KalamalkaKid I mean Windows still doesn't recognize them as headphones and calls them an "unspecified device". I still have the same problem no matter how I connect them.

Answer (score 7):

## Connect Quiet Comfort 35 II to PC

for Windows 10 do these steps:

1. plug your headphone to PC by USB cable
2. update your headphone software through [this site](http://btu.bose.com/)
3. Make your headphone "ready to pair" by pushing power switch to Bluetooth icon and hold
4. from Bluetooth setting click "Add bluetooth other device", confirm it paired
5. to connect it to PC and start the enjoyment go to "Devices and
   Printers" from Bluetooth setting
6. from Devices and Printers window double click on your headphone icon
   then press connect or visit
   https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/15290/windows-connect-bluetooth-device

or alternatively you could try [this guide](https://www.rogerperkin.co.uk/bose/how-to-connect-bose-wireless-headphones-to-computer/)

Comment: I did steps 1-4 but I can't do steps 5 or 6 because Windows doesn't recognize the device.

Comment: try removing the unspecified device first then do these steps

Comment: I did, but that didn't fix anything.

Comment: so what happens when you remove the device? Nothing? then what did you do?

Answer (score 3):

I am referring to the answer of @Kalamalka Kid.

Between step 4 and step 5, an extra step is needed to make this device an audio input/output device:

- 4.5a Find this device in your

  > Control Panel -> Hardware and Sound -> Device and Printers.

  Right click it and bring up Properties window. In the Properties window, select Services tab and click all feature you want to enable, i.e, Audio Sink, AudioWear, ... and Apply
- 4.5b Now the device is listed as audio device in your Bluetooth Device list, and you can connect to the device and use it as audio input/output device

Answer (score 1):

I was able to fix this with the following steps:

1. Goto Windows 10 "Bluetooth & Other Devices" settings
2. Under "Audio Devices" | Remove "Bose QuietComfort 35" or "Unspecified Device".
3. Under "Other Devices" | Remove ALL "LE-Bose QuietComfort 35" devices (2 were listed for me, both said 'Paired').
4. Turn off Bluetooth | Turn on Bluetooth
5. Enter Pairing mode in Windows 10
6. Enter Pairing mode on Bose QuietComfort 35 Headphones
7. Connect to "LE-Bose QuietComfort 35" bluetooth device (After this you should see another Bluetooth device appear called "Bose QuietComfort 35")
8. Connect to "Bose QuietComfort 35" bluetooth device

If you followed these steps correctly you should be good to go now.  The headphones should show up as "Bose QuietComfort 35" and say "Connected voice, music".

Comment: This did it for me, thank you so much! Couldn't get my QC 35 IIs to show up under microphone anymore and this solved it.

Answer (score 0):

Another thing to rule out while connecting

Hold the headphones close to your bluetooth connection. Mine was built into the motherboard, and it was either really poor range or something else was interfering with it. Once i held it close, it connected as per normal. When I was far away it would give me LE-MyBose (MyBose is the name i gave it) and a "laptop" style icon. This is also a sign its got a weak signal.

Don't under estimate poor Bluetooth or Range issues as a factor, as I went through 2-3 bluetooth devices before I was able to pinpoint that for some reason my router was interfering with my bluetooth signal (given it was nearby and they both operate on the same 2.4 GHz frequency band)